# My compiler keeps displaying this error "TypeError: add_node() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'"

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Python Method that adds a new Node to the linked list, given below is the code I have written but, when I execute it, the compiler keeps asking for some "positional argument" that I am missing apparently

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node
    
    
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node
        self.head.next = None
    
    def add_node(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        # checks if the linked list is empty or not
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        # seeker traverses through the list to find the final node of the list
        seeker = self.head
        # traversing through the list
        while seeker.next is not None:
        seeker = seeker.next
        # adding new node to the list
        seeker.next = new_node
        # setting the pointer to None/Null again
        new_node.next = None
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ListA = LinkedList
    ListA.add_node(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code should be like this:**

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
        self.head.next = None

    def add_node(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        # checks if the linked list is empty or not
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        # seeker traverses through the list to find the final node of the list
        seeker = self.head
        # traversing through the list
        while seeker.next is not None:
            seeker = seeker.next
        # adding new node to the list
        seeker.next = new_node
        # setting the pointer to None/Null again
        new_node.next = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ListA = LinkedList()
   ListA.add_node(5)
```

Comment: hey can you identify the mistake in my code that was causing the error, please. I am running into same kind of error again for my next project. Thank You

Comment: You can compare both code and you can identify the chages

Comment: I did it again for the millionth time and finally found the bug lol turns out I was missing parentheses "()" in object creation call. Thank you tho

Comment: ha ha ha. welcome. :). hope you learn from your mistakes. @JunaidAhmed